# Google sheets sending email -added var now throwing error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created this script and it is for all intent and purposes working, it is sending my emails etc. but for some reason the error message comes up

```
"Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient (line 17, file "Code")"
```

Line 17 is the subject var so not sure why it is expecting it to be an email. Anyone got an idea why it is?

Here is my code...

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("email sender")

        var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process

    var numRows = 1000; // Number of rows to process

    // Fetch the range of cells A2:C3

    var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:C");

    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i in data) {

        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
        var message = row[1]; // Second column
        var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
            htmlBody: message
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You're code works fine for me, do you have 1000 rows of email addresses?

Answer (score 1):

### This error means that some cell in column A are empty and thus do not contain valid E-mail addresses

- What about if instead 
  `sheet.getRange("A2:C");` you define `sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getlastRow,3);` using [numerical row and column references](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)? This will make sure that you don't run your code on empty rows
- Also, you can implement a statement checking either the recipient field is empty before sending an email:

```
if(emailAddress != "" && emailAddress != " "){
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    htmlBody: message
  });
}
```